# Tomcat is unresponsive in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I have a web app that runs on the top of a tomcat server. I am using eclipse as an IDE. My question is how to debug a tomcat application in Eclipse ? The application is basically a set of API calls and works well in the normal mode but whenever I change to debug mode, the server stops responding. The console shows no errors or warnings but I can't call the server over http anymore ? Every GET/POST call is timed out.

Comment: See if there is anything different in your Debug Configuration compared to your Run Configuration: Click on Tomcat in Server tab, then top menu Run -> Run Configuration...

Comment: No difference between both configurations. Are there any other areas where I should check?

Comment: An unexpected breakpoint perhaps?  Does pressing F8 help?